# new URL using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

how can i transform
http://domain.com/index.php?page=product&id=17&type=acos5-64-cryptographic-smart-card

to
http://domain.com/product/17/acos5-64-cryptographic-smart-card/

i just need to remove the variable names in the URL and leave their values there, 
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? The short answer is: "with mod_rewrite" http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: ive tried this 
RewriteRule products/(.*)/(.*)  index.php?page=products&id=$1&type=$2 but as you can see, my "page" variable is dynamic

Comment: i tried it this way, RewriteRule /(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$  index.php?page=$1&id=$2&id=$3 but the values that i get is wrong

Comment: @ramobrero It is better if you edit your question to add extra information to it, such as code. You can do this with the edit link under your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z\-]*)/?$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2&type=$3
```

Your rule was failing because:

- Rewrite paths don't start with '/'
- Possibly because `(.*)` is a little too greedy

Comment: it says, "page not found"

Comment: It works for me, do you have `RewriteEngine On` set in your .htaccess file?

Comment: yep, heres my .htaccess

=============================
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z\-]*)/$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2&type=$3
============================

and the links im testing

http://mydomain.com/index.php?page=product&id=17&type=acos5-64-cryptographic-smart-card - this works of course,
http://mydomain.com/product/17/acos5-64-cryptographic-smart-card/ - page not found

Comment: hi, ive tried replacing /product/17/acos5-64-cryptographic-smart-card/ with /product/17/asdasdsd/ could it be that the problem is with the "-" on my thrid parameter?

Comment: Wait, do you want the `/` on the end or not?

Comment: I updated to make the trailing slash optional, both of your example urls route properly for me with the supplied RewriteRule; you could technically change the last match group to `(.*)/?$` and it would catch anything

Comment: hello Rob, ive figured it out. ive , modified my old rewrite rule by adding ^ on my new link, that s what ive been missing all the time, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
```

$url = 'http://www.example.com/search.php?arg1=arg2';

$parts = parse_url($url);

$str = $parts['scheme'].'://'.$parts['host'].$parts['path'];

echo $str;
?>

Comment: i dont want to use php here, because i think this can be solved by using htaccess alone, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try below

RewriteRule ^product/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z-])/$ product.php?id=$1&productName=$2

17 is $1 and 
productname id $2